# how do i assign data from the subscribe call to a local variable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have tried to declare the variable inside the ngOnInit() but it goes out of scope. I would like to use the variable to iterate over the data and populate my html component. I have followed the answered questions on the same issue but most of them suggest calling a function inside the subscribe function, unfortunately in my case i just need to view the returned data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Playlist } from "../playlist";
import { PlaylistService } from "../playlist.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-market-place",
  templateUrl: "./market-place.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./market-place.component.css"],
})
export class MarketPlaceComponent implements OnInit {
  _playList: Playlist[] = []; //never gets assigned here

  errorMessage;
  constructor(private playListService: PlaylistService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playListService.getPlaylist().subscribe({
      next: (playList) => {
        this._playList = playList;
        console.log(this._playList); // am able to log the data but its never assigned to my _playList variable
      },
      error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
    });
  }
}
```

here is the service class

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Playlist } from "./playlist";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class PlaylistService {
  private playListUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/users";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPlaylist():Observable<Playlist[]> {
    return this.http.get<Playlist[]>(this.playListUrl).pipe(
      map((response) => <Playlist[]>response),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
}

private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse){
  let errorMessage = '';
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`
  }else {
    errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
  }
  console.error(errorMessage);
  return throwError(errorMessage)
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share how `getPlaylist()` is defined inside your service?

Comment: `
  getPlaylist():Observable<Playlist[]> {
    return this.http.get<Playlist[]>(this.playListUrl).pipe(
      map((response) => <Playlist[]>response),
      catchError(this.handleError),
    );
}
`

Comment: It would be better to append that code to your above question so it will be formatted. Could you also include what `handleError` does?

Comment: if `console.log(this._playList)` logs the correct values inside your next clause, it means it worked. where are you trying to use that local property later on though ? is it possible you're mistakenly thinking the call is synchronous and trying to use the value right after the subscribe call ?

Comment: @Stavm you are correct, the local variable already had the data, its only that i was using the wrong format in the template _playList instead of _playList.data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, what your Playlist object looks like, but maybe I have a simple idea, that could solve your issue. I suppose that console.log can not show the array of your objects. Did you try the following?

```
console.log(this._playList[0]);
```

Comment: that results into undefined